# PHP: Easy way to start PayPal checkout?

Tags: php, paypal

I have completely functional cart solution. All I want is the code where I actually pass the name of the products, the total, the return address and my paypal address so that it can direct me to a shopping cart. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

PayPal has a million different versions. What I've come to learn is that the one I need is called "paypal website payments". Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the [Website Payments Standard](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/wp_standard) is the way to go.

Basically, you create a form that has a few hidden fields ready to go (such as amount and what not) and then submit it.  You could even submit this with JavaScript, so it takes your customer right to PayPal to complete the transaction.

As an example:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="your_paypal_email_account" />
  <input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Order #1111111 for So-and-So" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="order_1111111" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.00" />
  <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00" />
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Comments" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF" />
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/some-page-to-return-to" />
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" />
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

You can find documentation on the additional parameters available here:  https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_websitepaymentsstandard_integrationguide.pdf

Comment: But i already have many cart items stored in sessions. Are you saying I must post with those inputs in my form? what address do I post to? What happens with more than one product?

Comment: @RD., I would use the entire "cart" as the "item".  PayPal does have its own shopping card you could integrate with, but you already have that, so there is no need.  Just pretend you have an item called "Order #12345" or whatever.  The top of the `<form>` tag didn't get pasted.  I will edit my answer with that address.

Comment: Sick! It works! Do you know how to set this so it goes via sandbox instead? Or is it not possible?

Comment: And how do you set the return url?

Comment: @RD., I believe the parameter for the return URL is simply, `return`, but I don't remember for certain.  For that option, as well as sandbox info, check that documentation I pointed you to.

Comment: Yes, the return url is `return`, additionally, using sandbox simply means swapping https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr for https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr in the `action`. Note: You'll need to have a working Sandbox seller account for this and be logged in on https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: btw, you can add `<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.example.com/some-page-to-return-to" />` to set a return url for when the user cancels the payment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as a reference the following source code: https://github.com/osCommerce/oscommerce2/blob/master/catalog/ext/modules/payment/paypal/express.php

Check out this comparison of PayPal merchant solutions: https://www.paypal.com/gr/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-comparison

Comment: the first link is broken