# Paypal checkout Firefox

Tags: php, paypal

I tried to make a Paypal checkout like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615964/php-easy-way-to-start-paypal-checkout). That works fine for Chrome but in Firefox I get stuck with this:

[image: paypal]

Form

```
<html><body>
Paypal redirect...<br />
<form name="frm" action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="bbbb@bbb.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://bbb.com/yeah.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Order #<?= $_SESSION['order_id'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="order_<?= $_SESSION['order_id'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?= $_SESSION['kasse_price'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Comments" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="DE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF" />
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/de_DE/i/btn/btn_paynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Mit PayPal bezahlen." />
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.frm.submit();
</script></body></html>
```

I checked the POST parameters send to Paypal. The look fine for both browsers. Notice that I automatically send the form. I know that is not nice but I don't know a better way to I try to make this work.

Any idea why it fails for Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about Firefox or Chrome, you need to be logged in with your developer account. You should have a developer account (set up here https://developer.paypal.com/) you used to define at least a buyer and a seller account.

To use the sandbox account you need to be logged in. You will have a "pseudo-login" for that buyer account you have but that's in the context you are already logged in with your dev account.